# Do I need to tie mangalasutra with exact 3 knots?

Tags: marriage, telugu, mangalasutra

In Telugu language, I often hear this words: "Moodu Mullu" means three knots of mangalasutra.

What happens if I tie with 2 knots instead of 3 knots?

Comment: Regional customs have regional variance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.